# Connecting .Net Core 2.2 project to XConnect in Azure Sitecore 9.2

Tags: xconnect, certificate

I'm using `Sitecore 9.2` scaled environment on Azure, and am trying to make a .Net core 2.2 project connects to XConnect, am following this [link](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/xconnect-tutorial--1--create-a-contact-and-an-interaction.html) from Sitecore documentation.

It worked fine in the .Net Console Application but when I tried it on the same machine and with the same code but in a .Net Core 2.2 project it gives the following error

```
Message = "One or more errors occurred. (The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden)"
XdbCollectionUnavailableException: The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden
```

And I checked that the certificate is self-signed and in the trusted root, the confusing thing is that its working fine in the console application but not in the .Net Core project.

Can someone please advise?

Comment: How are you running the .NET Core application? Standalone or through IIS? Depending on that you'll need to set access to the Client Certificate's private key. Check this post for details: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8561/xconnect-the-http-response-was-not-successful-unauthorized

Comment: Someone reported the same issue and Sitecore support got back for it. See if [this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16122/talking-to-xconnect-in-net-vs-netcore) helps.

Comment: @MarkLowe Am running the project using IIS Express

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16122/talking-to-xconnect-in-net-vs-netcore

Comment: .NetCore talks to certificates differently than .Net does. It has to be a "Digital Signature" cert.