# XConnect `The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden` on Azure

Tags: xconnect, azure, certificate

I'm using `Sitecore 9.2 scaled environment` on `Azure`, and am trying to make `.Net core 2.2` projects published on azure app service, not on the same instance of Sitecore azure connects to `XConnect`,

I was facing some problems on finding the certificate so I posted this [question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23204/how-to-replace-certificatehttpclienthandlermodifier-to-x509certificate2) and I had some help and found the solution by connecting through the below code:

```
public class CustomHandler : IHttpClientHandlerModifier {
    public void Process(HttpClientHandler handler) {
        X509Certificate cert = LoadYourCertificateHere();
        handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
    }
}
```

then used this:

```
 var certificateModifier = new CertificateValidationHttpClientHandlerModifier();
 certificateModifier.Process(handler);
```

Now I'm facing a new error `The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden`. I think this is because the certificate is not trusted by azure or something. So, Is there a way to move the certificate to local machine/root or currentUser/root? or Can someone please advise what to do?

please note: that everything is working fine locally with `.Net core` but when I published the code this was the error

Comment: I think your issue is that you need a certificate that .netcore trusts. Core needs extra security. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16122/talking-to-xconnect-in-net-vs-netcore

Comment: @ChrisAuer please note that everything is working fine locally with the same certificate and .Net core, but the problem begin when I published the code on Azure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally forgot to update the question:

According to [Microsoft document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate)
the problem was that the certificate has to be signed by a trusted certificate authority.